# Frontend does not get the node-session from Heroku, even though the session is stored in the database

Tags: node.js, session, heroku, session-cookies

My problem is, that the Frontend doesn't receive the session. Even though the session is stored in my database its not working. This problem only occurs when I use Heroku, locally it's working. I tried already a lot of solutions but none of them were working for me.
I hosted my frontend on Netlify with React and all of my backend is on Heroku.

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
    session({
        key: "userId",
        proxy: true,
        secret: "verySecureSecret123",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {
            secure: true,
            expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        },
    })
);
```

Comment: Please show `sessionStore` as well. Are you sure your database connection details are correct? You won't be able to just connect to localhost on Heroku like on your own PC.

Comment: @cbr The connection with the database works 100%, in the mySql Workbench I can see that it stored some sessions.

Comment: So what do you mean by "does not receive the session"? Please show the code and share what you expected to happen and what happened instead. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67947162/edit) your question to add details.